# Как динамически менять цвет TextView если задана круглая форма?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `TextView`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_rowMainFragment_pushBadge"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_badge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

в бекграунд я передаю `drawable`

```
android:background="@drawable/shape_badge"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@color/color_white"/>

</shape>
```

теперь получается мой `TextView` круглой формы и имеет белый цвет фона.

Теперь вопрос как поменять динамически цвет фона и при этом оставить круглую форму?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаю вот так:

```
Drawable shapeDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_back);
//Или
Drawable shapeDrawable = myImg.getBackground();

shapeDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
myImg.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);
```

Если делать с альфа каналом, то желательно на белом (нужном) фоне, так как происходит наложение.

Comment: Да только проблема в том, что у `TextView` нет метода `getBackgrondDrawable()`

Comment: А просто `getBackground();` не работает?

Comment: Так работает)) ок